# Incremental filename in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I was looking to save ping results to a text file and have got a crude script batch file running which is working.

What i want to achieve is that when ever the batch file is run(in this case when the system boots, the user will manually run it) the ping logfile is incremented as in it becomes 
Day 01 d:\pingresults.txt
Day 02 d:\pingresults+xx.txt

Or if the date can be appended at the end
The current batch script

```
    :start
@echo ****DO NOT CLOSE****
@echo off
DATE /T
TIME/T
echo %date% >> d:\pinghostname.txt
echo %time% >> d:\pinghostname.txt
ping 8.8.8.8 >> d:\pinghostname.txt
timeout /t 30
goto start
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly you want to add a timestamps to your files.

Something like this:

```
SET "job_start_date=%date:~6,10%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%"
```

which will produce (each part between `%...%` is taking part of the date):

```
20181109
```

So your script would look like this:

```
:start
@echo ****DO NOT CLOSE****
@echo off
DATE /T
TIME/T
SET "job_start_date=%date:~6,10%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%"
echo %date% >> d:\pinghostname_%job_start_date%.txt
echo %time% >> d:\pinghostname_%job_start_date%.txt
ping 8.8.8.8 >> d:\pinghostname_%job_start_date%.txt
timeout /t 30
goto start
```

then you will get a filename: `pinghostname_20181109.txt`

Comment: @JoelS You are welcome.Please accept the answer (you probably can't upvote it) when it satisfies your question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.  thank you